# return the larger value in comparison

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to this one (the pred is the final output)

```
name v1 v2 pred
a    2  2  v1
b    3  4  v2
c    5  5  v1
d    6  3  v1
e    2  3  v2
```

If v1 > v2, return v1, if v2> v1, return v2, if v1 = v2, return v1

my code is

```
df['pred'] = df[df[v1]>df[v2]] = 'v1'
df['pred'] = df[df[v1]<df[v2]] = 'v2'
df['pred'] = df[df[v1]=df[v2]] = 'v1'
```

is there anyway to solve this, the code is not working

Comment: Define "not working".  What's the expected output, and what's the actual output?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
import numpy as np
df['pred'] = np.where(df['v1'] >= df['v2'], 'v1', 'v2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `idxmax` on the columns axis. It will return for each row the first column that holds the maximal value.
This is exactly what you want.

```
 import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,2],[3,4],[5,5],[6,3],[2,3]], columns=['v1','v2'])

df['pred'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)

print(df)

   v1  v2 pred
0   2   2   v1
1   3   4   v2
2   5   5   v1
3   6   3   v1
4   2   3   v2
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users refer to and eventually apply this knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.